# Confidence regions for multivariate normal distributions

Tags: confidence-interval, chi-squared-test, multivariate-normal-distribution, hotelling-t2

From this post, [Confidence regions on bivariate normal distributions using $\hat{\Sigma}_{MLE}$ or $\mathbf{S}$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372336/confidence-regions-on-bivariate-normal-distributions-using-hat-sigma-mle?newreg=84dda7a002824e29a79c2630ac09a3a7), the equation

$(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^{T} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu}) \leq \chi_{p, \alpha}^2$

can be described by the parametric curve

$
\mathbf{x} = \boldsymbol{\mu} + \sqrt{\chi_{p, \alpha}^2} 
\mathbf{L} 
\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta)\\ 
\sin(\theta) 
\end{bmatrix}
$

for $ 0 < \theta < 2 \pi $

Is it possible to generalize to larger dimensions?

For example, for three dimensions

$
\mathbf{x} = \boldsymbol{\mu} + \sqrt{\chi_{p, \alpha}^2} \mathbf{L} 
\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi)\\ 
\cos(\theta) \sin(\phi)\\ 
\sin(\theta) 
\end{bmatrix}
$

for $ 0 < \theta < \pi $ and $ 0 < \phi < 2 \pi $

And so on?

Comment: Welcome to CV, Javier.  Of course it's possible!  But *how* do you want to generalize?  In $d$ dimensions the "curve" becomes a *hypersurface.* A good way to view this hypersurface is that it's a [sphere in Mahalanobis coordinates.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62147/919)  There are many ways to parameterize it, if you need to -- but it's rare to need to.  Usually all you need is to determine whether a point lies inside or outside this sphere, and that's easily done.

Comment: Thank you. I want to sample or generate points at the boundary of the hypersurface. So I mean if its possible to generalize the parametrization

Comment: Please make that your question, then.  The reason is that parameterization is only a means to that end *and is both unnecessary and overly complicated.*  The simple answer is that to sample the sphere you can choose one point and then rotate it (randomly or deterministically).  A random rotation is effected by a random orthogonal transformation, [which is incredibly easy to obtain,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143903) but orthogonal transformations do not parameterize the sphere.